# Youtube Data API(v3) doesn't return 'published_at' attribute at a specific channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

channel_id : UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ
web : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ

[request]

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ&key={API_KEY}&maxResults=50&part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatistics%2CbrandingSettings
```

We couldn't get this channel's published_at attribute by using Youtube Data API(v3). 
There is 'published_at' field in the return of the API, but a value is nil.

We aren't able to see that when this channel is published on the web(Is it able to hide such information?)

Does this problem only related to this channel?

Comment: The date is not set even in the about section of YouTube channel page. Generally the `published_at` will be present, but this looks channel for YouTube itself. In my opinion this channel is an exceptional one.

Comment: Also I don't think there is an option to hide the `published_at` in API level

Comment: please post the full request you are making.   I suspect thats one of Youtube's official channels they may not release all the information to you

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
I described a full request.